# how to use old URls as it is in new drupal site

Tags: .htaccess, drupal, url-rewriting, drupal-7

I am migrating an asp site to drupal.the existing site node  URL is as

```
story.asp?sectioncode=1&storycode=49667&c=1
```

to use the same urls in drupal site i add the URL in URL aliases.when i click on any article it it showing as

```
story.asp%3Fsectioncode%3D1%26storycode%3D49667%26c%3D1
```

in the browser.how to remove `%3D,%26,%3F` from the URL and when i copy and paste the old url in the browser it is not redirecting me to the actual page giving `404` not found page.could some one please help me how to manage my old URLs as it is in new site.

Answer (score 1):

You're not supposed to type something like `story.asp?sectioncode=1&storycode=49667&c=1` as an URL alias.

There's a better way to do that. Try installing [redirect module](http://drupal.org/project/redirect) and add a new 301 redirect rule from `story.asp?sectioncode=1&storycode=49667&c=1` to your new node's URL `node/1`.

So, whatever any user / search engine visits `story.asp?sectioncode=1&storycode=49667&c=1`, they will be redirected to `node/1`. or whatever the path you have given to the 301 redirect rule.

Hope this Helps... Muhammad.